# How to Lower the Quality of Wordpress Featured Image (PHP)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, resolution

All the posts I find are about people complaining that the image quality is too low however my images are too high quality and I would like to lower them to increase page speed. How could I set the resolution to 300 width by auto height in my functions.php file? Here is the code I am using to call it in my functions.php:

(Note): I do not want to hard crop or soft crop, I just want to affect resolution.

PHP:

```
<?php

function ericshio_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );  

/* Post Thumbnails */

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'image', 'video' ));
    register_nav_menu('Primary','Main Navigation');
}

add_action('init', 'ericshio_theme_setup');

?>
```